# Create a silent unattended installation for SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, installation, setup-project

I have an application that uses a SQL Server 2005 database.

I'm trying to create a setup for my application, but I want to include SQL Server 2005 installation too.

Is there any way to include a silent unattended installation process of SQL Server 2005 ?

Thank you !

Comment: You should probably tag the language that your application is in.

Comment: Id doesn't matter.  What I'm asking for is how to create a silent unattended setup for SQL server 2005. Just to run something and the installation should go to the end silently without any user intervention if possible. Is possible to do that ?

Comment: I don't know.  This isn't a sql-server programming question.  You either want to do this install from a sql-server installation disk, in which case it is a dba question, or you want to do it from an application you are writing, in which case it is a question for programmers in the application language you are using.   Or, if you are actually asking if there is a SQL command that will do this, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

You can [create an configuration file](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=%22sql+server+2005%22+unattended) for the install. But, the real question is whether you should. I know of no other product that will install a server grade version of SQL Server as part of their install process. Not even Microsoft's own products do this.

Are you only going to run this in integrated security mode? Or, do you plan on setting the sa account up with a hard coded password?

Are you going to create a named instance? How will you make sure that the end user doesn't already have a SQL instance with that name?

Are you going to set the security properly so that this SQL instance doesn't become part of a bot network when a vulnerability is discovered and the person that installed your product doesn't apply any service packs?

Are you going to accept responsibility for licensing the server instance?

Just don't do it. Make your product installer ask for credentials and a server instance to use. Then, build your database(s) and store away whatever is needed to access the database by your product.

If you need to use a private SQL type of instance, there are other alternatives (such as SqlExpress).

Comment: Ok friend. no other product that you know do this. But for everything there's a first time. I'm planning to do with sa and a password. Yes I plan to create an instance name. I will make a test on my main setup if the Sql server is installed with the correct instance name , then I will skip the installation. I will buy sql server licenses , so on every "setup"  that I give to client I want to include a regular license. So is there any possibility to make a completely silent and unattended installation?